# Mathematica Lattice Reduce Command

Tags: linear-algebra, implementation-details, lattices

I'm going through a very old copy of "Mathematica: A System for Doing Mathematics by Computer" for self practice.

I'm on chapter 3, and ran into the `LatticeReduce` command.

**Quick question**: Is the lattice reduce command just basically just doing Gram Schmidt Orthogonalization?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess I should add that lattice reduction uses Gram-Schmidt in its processing.

Answer (score 7):

No, it is not doing a Gram-Schmidt procedure.

One way to note that this is distinct from Gram-Schmidt is that Gram-Schmidt produces an orthonormal basis, whereas the example outputs in the Documentation Center page for `LatticeReduce` are neither normalized nor orthogonal.

Instead, `LatticeReduce` returns a basis $B$ comprised of linear combinations of integer multiples of the original basis vectors with minimal orthogonality defect, i.e., it minimizes
$$\delta(\mathbf B)=\frac{\prod\limits_{i=1}^N \left|B_i\right|}{\sqrt{\det\left(\mathbf B^\top\mathbf B\right)}}.$$
This has the effect of making the resulting basis "most cube-like". Szabolcs mentioned in a comment that the internal implementation is the [Lenstra-Lenstra-Lovász algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm) (see [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#27255)).

See the Wiki page on [lattice reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_reduction) for more info.

Comment: Not exactly minimizes, but approximately, in the sense made precise in LLL.

Comment: In particular, it is mentioned in the docs that the method implemented is the [Storjohann version](http://dx.doi.org/10.3929/ethz-a-006651659) of LLL.

Comment: @J.M. I had no idea that was in the documentation (even worse, it had to be me that put it there). As of 10.2 we use a method due to [Nguyen and Stehle](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/damien.stehle/FPLLL.html). Sometimes referred to as L^2 (though there are now at least two such).

Comment: @Daniel, oh, nice! I was wondering when it'd be implemented. Maybe someday I can try out 10.2... :)

Comment: @J.M. Actually it was implemented a few years ago, we just never told anyone. Was available via undocumented `SystemOption`. Some day I may even wrap up L1+ (if it doesn't wrap me up first).