# What values of $\delta$ and $\eta$ are being used in LatticeReduce?

Tags: linear-algebra, implementation-details, lattices

The Lenstra–Lenstra–Lovász algorithm has a parameter $\delta$ with $1/4 < \delta < 1$, where roughly speaking the closer $\delta$ is to 1 the longer it takes, but the better basis reduction you get.
`Options[LatticeReduce]` returns `{}`, so what value of $\delta$ is `LatticeReduce` using?
Is there any way to tell it which $\delta$ you want LLL executed with?

---

If *Mathematica* is using Nguyen-Stehle, then there is a second parameter $\eta$ with $1/2 < \eta < \sqrt{\delta}$. What is the default for that in `LatticeReduce`, and how can I change $\eta$?

Thank you for your prompt and informative reply.

Comment: That other parameter is fixed to .51 and only changed for too-small $\delta$ (or maybe we change $\delta$, I forget). In any case it is not configurable.

Comment: I should clarify: .51 is actually what they refer to as $\overline{\eta}$ rather than $\eta$. Computations are done with the former whereas results are guaranteed in terms of the latter.

Answer (score 8):

In [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66029/66031#comment251549_66031), it is noted that `LatticeReduce[]` is now using the [Nguyen-Stehle](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/damien.stehle/FPLLL.html) variant of LLL, so any results you might see from `LatticeReduce[]` can be different from a "classical" implementation of LLL.

Having said this, `LatticeReduce[]` does take options, but through a not too transparent interface:

```
SetSystemOptions["LatticeReduceOptions" ->
                 {"LatticeReduceRatioParameter" -> .75}];
```

The list of default option settings is accessible through `SystemOptions["LatticeReduceOptions"]`; the default setting of `Automatic` for `"LatticeReduceRatioParameter"` indicates that the choice is made internally, depending on the input matrix.

Comment: (I should hasten to add that I picked all of this from Daniel Lichtblau. Maybe he'll have more to say when he sees this.)

Comment: All correct. The `Automatic` setting is due to the fact that .75 is used for integer/rational input (the usual case) whereas .8 is used for Gaussian integer/rational input. The 3/4 default predates me and the 4/5 for Gaussians was from when I extended `LatticeReduce` to handle those (more than 20 years ago, from what I can see in the commit logs).

Comment: @Daniel, I didn't know a different setting was needed for Gaussian integers! Do you know a reference for this? (The 0.75 setting was already in the original LLL paper, IIRC.)

Comment: For Gaussians it need not be .8 but it is required to be larger than 1/2 if I remember correctly. You are correct that .75 is used in LLL (the paper). Here is a reference that I think is relevant: Huguette Napias. *[A generalization of the LLL-algorithm over Euclidean rings or orders](http://www.numdam.org/item/JTNB_1996__8_2_387_0)*. Journal de Theorie des Nombres de Bordeaux 8(2):387-396. 1996. There must be older knowledge though, since I implemented the Gaussian case a couple of years before that.