# What is LatticeReduce minimizing?

Tags: linear-algebra, implementation-details, lattices

According to the manual page on **LatticeReduce**, *The product of the norms of lattice vectors will decrease.* The claim seems to be true for small lattices, but, I cannot confirm this for higher dimensional lattices. For example,

```
dim = 10;
a = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {dim, dim}];
b = LatticeReduce[a];
N[Times @@ (Norm /@ #)] & /@ {a, b}
```

gives {7.63814*10^12, 6.36906*10^11}, as claimed. But,

```
dim = 50;
a = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {dim, dim}];
b = LatticeReduce[a];
N[Times @@ (Norm /@ #)] & /@ {a, b}
```

resulted in
{3.58054*10^81, 9.85951*10^83}.

My question is: **What is the measure of lattice complexity which LatticeReduce is really trying to minimize?**

The $\delta(B)$ which is explained in DumpsterDoofus's answer to [Mathematica Lattice Reduce Command](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66029/)
is not decreasing in the above example.

I'm using Mathematica 13.0.1.

Comment: Good observation. A smaller example that is in conflict with the documentation is `a={{1,3,-2},{2,0,3},{3,-1,0}}; b=LatticeReduce[a]; Times@@(Norm/@a)>=Times@@(Norm/@b)` which gives `False`, so I agree that statement in the documentation is misleading.

Comment: A remark about the [answer by @DumpsterDoofus](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66031/85954) that you mention: The command `LatticeReduce` preserves the determinant, `Det[Transpose[a].a]===Det[Transpose[b].b]`. Therefore the denominator in the quantity $\delta$ defined by @DumpsterDoofus does not actually change under `LatticeReduce` and was probably only included for conceptual reasons, to have the interpretation of measuring "cube-likeness".

Comment: Did you read the comments after [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66031/85954)? It is pointed out there that $\delta$ is not actually minimized, and it refers to [LLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm) for details.

Comment: Thanks. I missed the comment. As far as I tested in 50 dim lattice, $\delta$ almost always increased. I just wonder how MMA concludes the output is "better" than the input lattice. There must be some criterion .... Maybe I should read the original LLL paper.